# When is ternary operator worse than simple if-else block?

Tags: operators, block, if-statement, ternary-operator

I wonder: "when is ternary operator worse than just using 'if-else' block?"

I suppose, it could be with debug-time (e.g. ternary operator is bad for debugging)

Is such beauty useful? Maybe there are some situations when simple if-else block is better for using?

thank you

Comment: IMHO, ternary operators are used almost everywhere. Any programmer with a decent experience should have no issues debugging them.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai As I have tested some weak IDE | debuggers may skip exactly expressions with ternary operator, but not skipping if there was just if-else block. Visual Studio works fine with them, but less famous and powerful IDE/debuggers often skips such expressions and you may not just to look through debugger some values at the debug-time inside this expression with ternary operator.

Comment: As Mark answered below, you are referring to a case where simply looking at the expression does not tell you anything. Might as well go for if-else then.

Comment: The IDE shouldn't have an impact on how you structure and write your code, IMO. If your code is so poorly structured that you can't look up a few lines from a breakpoint to see that that a ternary is altering a value, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: We write code to solve a given programming problem. Sometimes solving the problem means being able to easily step through the code with any debugger. To argue that the ternary expression is more important than the more pragmatic ability to step through the code is to fetishize code 'elegance' over solving the problem in front of you. Yes, ideally all debuggers should be able to step through ternaries and all programmers would know the nuances of their debugger, but many can't, and I like to see what my code is doing so I don't use ternaries. You lose readability and gain nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ternary operator is useful when you want to conditionally evaluate one of two simple expressions and do something simple with the result (e.g. assign it to a variable or return it). Something like this is an acceptable use of the ternary operator:

```
var status = a.isActive() ? a.status : defaultStatus;
```

If your code is more complicated than this then it is usually clearer to use an if statement otherwise you risk trying to do too much in a single line of code. It's not just about ease of debugging - a long line with a complex expression can be difficult to understand.

In many languages it is not allowed to use statements (as opposed to expressions) in a `? :` expression. If you need to execute a series of statements then you have no choice except to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Could it be not useful even for simple expressions at debug time ( or it's the question more about debugger, maybe one will give you correct debug, but others will just skip ternary operator, isn't it? )

Comment: @OlegOrlov: The ternary operator won't be skipped. It might be more difficult to step through the code in a ternary operator compared to the same code written as an `if` statement, though this depends on how will your IDE supports it.

Answer (score 2):

Ternaries should be used for very simple branching within a single statement only, IMO. I would say that any time you're tempted to write a ternary on multiple lines for clarity, it's time to use some other form of branching. I also personally find compound ternary operators very hard to read and consider it bad form.

And forget the IDE. If you have to be able to break on absolutely every little thing in your debugger in order to understand your code, you have a much larger structural issue.

In JavaScript I tend to only use ternaries in my initial var declaration blocks at the beginning of a function when I'm setting things up based on the function arguments. They primarily evaluate on very simple things like the lengths of arrays, existence of optional parameters, or types of params. Beyond that initial preparation point, logic typically gets more complicated or requires more than one simple check so it makes more sense to spell it out with block-based switching structures or some form of mapping.

But think in terms of legibility without the IDE first. Structuring your code well as if you had no IDE will always help you understand the code better, IMO.